# How can census population size be smaller than the effective population size in some species? is that possible?

Tags: genetics, population-genetics, conservation-biology

The only way I can think this could happen is through a recent population bottleneck. Can it be possible though ?

Comment: Why are you asking? Have you encountered a case where the census population is considered smaller than the effective pop size?